# How to get the list of logged persons?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a got a task to find out the list of persons who are logged in to the  application. I have taken the logged user to a session. Is there any way to get the count of logged users? 
for eg: in chatting box, we can see the count of persons who are online.

How can I do this? Please help

Comment: You could check about sockets.

Comment: Why don't you take one extra column to your database **logged** with status **true/false** and get **select * from logged_master where logged='true'** you will get your data

Comment: @dholakiyaankit So what if the user closes his/hers browser? In your way, the user is still logged in.

Comment: @Bondye in that case there are plenty of ways to check that user has closed browser or not?

Comment: What about sockets ? explain me and @nithin also

Comment: @dholakiyaankit You can never be sure if the user close the browser the normal way, same as pressing a logout button. Via sockets you can monitor connections.

Comment: Don't understand you can put it as a answer

Comment: @nithin is this your question?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit- your idea is good..But how can I know the browser is closed or not?
I didn't get Bondye yet

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .net you can easily achieve this by using SignalR.
Take a look at those tutorials (especially the second one, that shows how to handle logged-in users)

[Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2.0 and MVC](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5)
[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections)